# Map a 2d 2-channel numpy array to a 2d 1-channel numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a 2d 2-channel (3d) numpy array:

```
[[[-1, -1], [0, -1], [1, -1]],
 [[-1,  0], [0,  0], [1,  0]],
 [[-1,  1], [0,  1], [1,  1]]]
```

I want to map this to a 2d 1-channel (3d) numpy array:

```
[[[0], [1], [2]],
 [[3], [4], [5]],
 [[6], [7], [8]]]
```

So for example I had the following array

```
[[[-1, -1], [0, 0], [1, 1]],

 [[ 0,  0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

After applying the mapping I should get.

```
[[[0], [4], [8]],
 [[4], [5], [8]]]
```

Since `[-1, -1] == [0]`, `[0, 0] == [4]`, and so on in the mapping.

I am writing a python program to preprocess images in CIELAB space. The L* has been stripped off leaving me with 'ab'. I want to convert individual pixels of ab to classes.

Comment: Can you describe the rule more clearly, I lost you on the second to last step.

Comment: Those are 3D arrays. Please post an MCVE using a `for` loop, or at least write out the function you want to apply to each element

Comment: I've updated my answer some. Hope you like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's generate your lookup arrays to get a hint. First the template:

```
ROWS = 3
COLS = 3

template = np.arange(ROWS * COLS).reshape(ROWS, COLS, 1)
```

This is equivalent to

```
template = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]],
                     [[3], [4], [5]],
                     [[6], [7], [8]]])
```

Then the input grid:

```
ROW_OFFSET = -1
COL_OFFSET = -1

grid = np.stack(np.mgrid[ROW_OFFSET:ROWS + ROW_OFFSET,
                         COL_OFFSET:COLS + COL_OFFSET], 2)
```

This is equivalent to

```
grid = np.array([[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1]],
                 [[ 0, -1], [ 0, 0], [ 0, 1]],
                 [[ 1, -1], [ 1, 0], [ 1, 1]]])
```

Given how we made `grid`, it should be clear that the "channels" are the row and column index, up to the offset. So given an index array, you can map it into `template` using fancy indexing:

```
index = np.array([[[-1,-1], [0, 0], [1, 1]],
                  [[ 0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]])

result = template[index[:, :, 0] - ROW_OFFSET, index[:, :, 1] - COL_OFFSET, :]
```

If your `template` always fits the pattern shown above, you don't need indexing at all. You can just generate the result directly from `COLS` and the grid offsets:

```
result = (index[:, :, 0] - ROW_OFFSET) * COLS + index[:, :, 1] - COL_OFFSET
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[-1,-1], [0,-1], [1,-1]],
 [[-1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0]],
 [[-1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1]]])

b = np.array([[[-1,-1], [0, 0], [1, 1]],
 [[ 0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]])

width = len(a[0])
start_row = a[0][0][0]
start_col = a[0][0][1]


result = []
for rows in b:
    line = []
    for d in rows:
        n = (d[1] - start_col) * width + d[0] -  start_row
        line.append([n])
    result.append(line)
        
result = np.asarray(result)
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yup this is what I was trying to do, but with images. I have a 2 channel image and I want to map them to 1 channel. The images have about 500 pixels in width and height. So I was wondering if it was possible to achieve it without for loops. Thank you!

Comment: Without looping? This method is O(n), and you want an O(1) solution?

Comment: No I was wondering if there was a solution that utilized numpy indexing instead of a for loop.